# Ordering Wordpress posts by id - exact order

Tags: php, wordpress

it seems i can not find what i am looking for anywhere.

i am using the code below to show posts, using their ids.the problem is that i can't sort them the way i want - i need to order them exactly in order of the ids (currently it is sorting asc or desc.

i don't need that, i only want to show them exactly in the order of the ids)

```
<?php 
$query_args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'category' => '3', 'numberposts'=>'50', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'include' => '100,124,122');
$query_posts = get_posts($query_args);
$last_query = end($query_posts);
foreach ($query_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
```

any ideas?

Comment: nothing? i just need not to order the ids, to display them as they are

Comment: Do you want to sort them by the IDs in the database? If yes, then http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters should do it for you. Or, are you looking to order the posts by an exact specific order as determined by another list of IDs that you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was halfway through writing an answer when I found [wyfel's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11103/264) to a similar question on [the WordPress stack exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  Short of adding a global to store the IDs (rather than hard-coding them), it's what I planned to suggest (even down to the MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function).